# defer, recover и panic отличие от try-catch

Tags: golang

В чём отличие от try-catch в большинстве языков конструкции defer-recover-panic?

Как panic сказывается на производительности? Подумываю о том, чтобы вместо постоянного проброса наверх ошибок, в отдельных местах использовать связку defer+recover+panic.

Какие есть ещё нюансы, помимо производительности7?

Comment: если бы не сказывалось, то все бы так и делали

Comment: Panic используется для [неожиданных](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/handling-panics-in-go-ru) ошибок, а проброс выше ошибок (return err) - для ожидаемых, когда есть возможность их обработать выше. О каких нюансах вопрос?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Основной задачей является избавиться от лапшички, которая превращается в адище при наличии большого количества обрабатываемых ошибок. Как это сделать не ясно. Под нюансами я подразумеваю, например, ухудшение производительности. Есть ли какие-лио замеры? Почему этого делать не советуют хочется также понять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличие `panic/recover` от `try/catch` в других языках в том, что оно полностью прерывает выполнение текущей функции.

Для большей наглядности:

```js
function doSomething() {
 throw "panic";
}

(() => {
  try {
    doSomething();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  console.log("after try/catch")
})()
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func doSomething() {
    panic("panic")
}

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s", err, debug.Stack())
        }
    }()

    doSomething()

    fmt.Print("after panic")
}
```

В первом примере текст `after try/catch` будет выведен, во втором случае `after panic` не выведется, т.к. функция `main` закончит свое выполнение.

Так же `recover` может быть только один, грубо говоря, как-будто всё тело функции обернуто в `try/catch`, что делает его менее гибким. [Читал](https://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions), что это сделанно намеренно для избежания злоупотреблений.

На счет производительности вопрос довольно сложный, определенно `panic/recover` медленней, но я затрудняюсь назвать разницу, ибо довольно сложно написать бенчмарк с одинаковым применением.

Я ни в коем случае не претендую на корректность бенчмарка, надеюсь на правки со стороны коллег в комментариях.

Запускал на ноутбучном `i5`, `go version go1.15 linux/amd64`

```
BenchmarkPanicDefer-4            3006555               353 ns/op
BenchmarkErrorCatch-4           1000000000               0.502 ns/op
```

Моя попытка написать бенчмарк:

```go
package main

import (
  "errors"
  "testing"
)

func getPanic() {
  panic("")
}

func PanicDefer() {
  defer func() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
      // do something
    }
  }()

  getPanic()
}

func getError() error {
  return errors.New("")
}

func CatchError() {
  if err := getError(); err != nil {
    // do something
  }
}

func BenchmarkPanicDefer(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    PanicDefer()
  }
}

func BenchmarkErrorCatch(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    CatchError()
  }
}
```

Понятное дело, что условия не совсем равные, я попытался сделать их максимально близкими к реальному приложению.

Как правило между "ошибка" и "исключение" границы довольно размыты, сильно зависит от контекста. В других языках `try/catch` это универсальное решение для обоих случаев.
На мой взгляд, если использование `panic/recover` в каком-то конкретном месте делает код чище, то ничего не мешает так писать.